# org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured! Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_service
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
# DDL generation
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

I have used opensession() instead of getCurrentSession() and it worked for me the only thing that I do not want to open a session in each transaction so this does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure the context to use for the "current session" as you can read in the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#architecture-current-session